# How to import companion object of an enum?

Tags: kotlin, enums

This code doesn't compile, because companion object members aren't imported:

```
import Color.*

enum class Color {
    R, G, B;
    companion object {
        val X = 1
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(R.ordinal)
    println(X)
}
```

I have to write `Color.X` instead of simply `X`.
How to import also companion stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

```
import Color.Companion.X
```

I found this by selecting the "X" in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio and using "Add import for..."